# DynamoDBMapper queryPage working with non sort key as filter parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

From the dynamoDBMapper [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Methods.html#d0e32126)

Querypage:

> Queries a table or secondary index and returns a single page of
>   matching results. As with the query method, you must specify a
>   partition key value and a **query filter that is applied on the sort key
>   attribute**. However, queryPage will only return the first "page" of
>   data - that is, the amount of data that will fit within 1 MB.

I've applied query filter on a attribute which is not a sort key. But everything works. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think that particular statement is misleading in the documentation. You can apply query-filter/filter-expression on any non-key attributes, but you cannot apply filter expression on key attributes :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#FilteringResults

You can send your feedback ("Feedback" button at the bottom of the doc page) to Amazon. I think they're pretty responsive for the feedbacks they receive.